# Is there anything like sanitize for controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

Is there anything like sanitize for controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is as follows:

```
# in application_controller.rb
def helpers
  Helper.instance
end

class Helper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
end

# in your controller
def index 
  @message = "Sanitized #{helpers.sanitize(...)}"
end
```

This namespaces your helpers in the controller, kind of, by extending an inner class.  I hope this helps!

Comment: btw, in future you should try to add more info to your question.

Comment: I get the following error: `undefined method `instance' for ApplicationController::Helper:Class` What might be the problem?

Comment: This might work for some other helpers but calling `sanitize` causes an error: 'undefined method white_list_sanitizer'.

Comment: got `undefined method 'instance' `, used with Yuan Cheung's answer :)

Answer (score 4):

via: http://www.adaruby.com/2009/12/16/how-to-use-actionview-helpers-in-your-rails-controller/

I think the Helper class should be:

```
class Helper
  include Singleton
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
end
```